# Sqlite inserting '(null)' for nil NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

While trying to insert records into the database, I leveraged the user to leave some fields empty, i.e. nil strings. Now, when I insert the data into the DB then instead of a nil value I get (null) in each column whose datasource was nil. When I fetch the records from the database and display it to user the values he left empty are now being shown as (null).

I can implement the logic to check for this '(null)' string but I guess there should be some way to handle it at the Database level. I mean if I insert a nil value then it should be nil or empty not (null) string. Can anyone help me out with it?
Thanks

Comment: are you getting null as a string or you are getting null value???

Comment: nil ie no value IS NULL in the database - an empty string is a non nil NSString one that has length 0

Comment: when I retrieve the record I get (null) as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use string formatting with a "%@" format specifier, and the corresponding object pointer value is `nil`, the formatted string gets "(null)" in that position.  So, either you or a library you're using is doing that.

Outside of string formatting, I'm not aware of anything that will produce "(null)" out of the blue.

Comment: Ya, I am using %@ in building query within the +stringWithFormat method. Any alternative or solution to that? apart from checking each string to be not nil?

Comment: You probably have to check for `nil`. What do you expect your formatted query to look like if a string argument is `nil`?

Comment: Guess I saw that coming :)... hmmm I think replace any nil strings with "" i.e. a string with zero length. Would it work?

Comment: I don't know if that would work in terms of SQLite and your database design. It might. You can do something like `NSString* value = textField.text; if (!value) value = @"";`. Or, when formatting, you can do `[NSString stringWithFormat"blah %@ blah", (value ? value : @"")]`.

Comment: Great Ken. I am convinced by undertow that it's gonna work :). I'll give it a try. Another thought came up that I'd instantiate my NSStrings with NULL value by default, that way I can even skip the check while formatting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Ken Thomases' answer is correct in that you're getting `"(null)"` out of the database because you're putting `"(null)"` into the database without realising it.

I just wanted to add that when you're inserting records into the database you can ensure that optional Strings are inserted as `NULL` values as follows:

```
let nullableStringValue: String

if let stringValue = myObject.myOptionalProperty {
    nullableStringValue = "'\(stringValue)'"
} else {
    nullableStringValue = "NULL"
}

let insertStatement = "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyNullableColumn) VALUES (\(nullableStringValue))"

// proceed to execute the insert statement
```

And then when you're querying the database you can read the possibly null value as follows:

```
let myNullableColumnText: String?

if let myNullableColumnTextPointer = sqlite3_column_text(compiledSelectStatement, columnIndex) {
    myNullableColumnText = String(cString: myNullableColumnTextPointer)
} else {
    myNullableColumnText = nil
}
```